# On Negative Lengths And Positive Hypotenuses In Trigonometry

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

There is something confusing me in trigonometry. Specifically, in unit circles, when angle theta goes beyond 90 degrees, we can have triangles that have negative lengths in the unit circle, if you see what I mean. What confuses me about this is how can shapes have negative lengths? This is my first question.

My second question is that if the lengths of the triangle are negative, then why is the hypotenuse of the triangle/radius of the unit circle still positive? I get that it is positive because it is given by x^2 + y^2=1 (because of the square it must be positive). But still. Shouldn't it be negative because considering sides are negative, shouldn't there be some reflection of that in the hypotenuse? After,all it is facing the negative direction!

Comment: negative lengths? Surely not!

Comment: The coordinates of those points may be negative.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are getting at here, but given a point $O$ on a line and a point $A$ at distance $d$ from $O$, there are two possibilities for $A$. It can be convenient to distinguish these by giving them different signs. And when using co-ordinates, signs become important (this can be seen as a systematic extension of the idea of signed distances). But I think you may be getting at something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trigonometric functions are defined for angles between 0 an 90° over the triangles. I assume you understood this idea.

For multiple reasons one wanted to extend the functions to other angles, so one has to come up with a creative idea.

If you would plot the triangles on the unit circle, you see that the trigonometric functions have something to do with the x any y coordiantes of the points on the unit circle.

More concrete: For all angles between 0 and 90° we have that 
$sin(\alpha) = y/x$, where $x$y and $y$ are the coordinates of the point on the unit circle.

Then people just generalized this rule to every point on the unit circle. For degrees above $90$ the definition has not directly something to do with the triangles, it's just an extension.

Hence we don't need any triangles with negative length

Comment: Thanks for the response. Next question though. If the lengths are negative, why would the hypotenuse be positive though? I get that it is positive because it is given by x^2 + y^2=1 (because of the square it must be positive). But still shouldn’t the hypotenuse of the triangle be negative, to reflect the direction the other sides of the triangle are going?

Comment: @EthanChan This answer never mentions "negative lengths". It is you who keeps harping on this, and I for one cannot see what you mean by it.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Well when you look at a unit circle, there are some triangles that can be formed in the negative quadrants of the circle, so they have negative lengths. A triangle formed in the third quadrant would have both a negative base and a negative height. My question is though, why isn't the hypotenuse negative then? I know it isn't because it is given by x^2 + y^2=1. But still! Since it is facing the negative direction, shouldn't there be some reflection in it's hypotenuse that it's facing the negative direction, and therefore the hypotenuse should be negative?

Comment: @EthanChan Again you are harping on about "negative length". Even in "negative quadrants", line segments have lengths that are positive....